# Не полный экспорт из mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, denwer

Делаю экспорт таблицы из Денвера- в таблице 450к записей. А экспортируется всего 3785. Не выдает ошибок. В экспорте стоит- "Выгрузить все строки". Почему такое может происходить? Как обнаружить причину? Как ее устранить?

Comment: *Как обнаружить причину?* Посмотреть текст запроса, приходящего на MySQL.

Comment: Приведите текст команды.

Comment: @Akina Не подскажите как это сделать- где именно они приходят? Через консоль не умею с БД работать- просто нажимаю на кнопку Экспорт/ок.

Comment: *как это сделать* На MySQL-сервере: 1) Включить General Log 2) Выполнить операцию 3) Выключить General Log 4) Посмотреть General Log, выделить запросы от этого процесса и проанализировать.

Comment: @Akina благодарю за подробное объяснение. https://my-files.ru/m2igiy  Если подскажите буду благодарен, но не стоит утруждаться- сам раскурю, если что- надеюсь это тот файл что нужно.

Comment: Увы, огорчу. Экспорт выполняется не запросами. Во всяком случае в этом логе их нет. Вероятно, запускается mysqldump или иная утилита экспорта, не использующая запросы. Ловите её запуск и смотрите, какие команды и опции используются.

Comment: В самой базе данных отображается только 100к строк с обеих сторон- а если смотреть внутренние, то там только шапка, а записи не отображаются. Явно какое то бутылочное горлышко...